# pmd_camcube_3_ros_pkg error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have a problem when running pmd_camcube_3_ros_pkg. I have follow the instruction to install the pkg but when I run the  rosrun pmd_camcube_3_ros_pkg pmd_camcube_3_node

I get an error:
Could not connect:
could not open: could not find PMD USB device
Cannot Initialize Camera :( Check the parameters and try again!!

Do somebody know what is the error about.
P.S. I am using fuerte and Ubuntu 12.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49399/pmd_camcube_3_ros_pkg-error/) by [harke](https://answers.ros.org/users/3357/harke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first thing which comes to my mind: did you set up the udev-rules to be able to access the CamCube via USB?

Quick google for an example gave http://zfred.blogspot.de/2012/09/pmd-cabecube-30-and-ubuntu-1204.html, although I haven't checked it for correctness ;-)

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0